# Generating id for each collapsible panel group dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Created a collapsible panel group dynamically with button click, my question is how can I generate id for each created panel.
Here is my jquery code:

```js
var panel = '<div class="panel panel-default">';
    panel += '<div class="panel-heading">';
    panel += '<h4 class="panel-title">';
    panel += '<span class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#1">' + $('#queuename').val();
    panel += '</span>';
    panel += '</h4>';
    panel += '</div>';
    panel += '<div id="1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">';
    panel += '<div class="panel-body"></div>';
    panel += '</div>';
    panel += '</div>';
    panel += '</div>';
var hash = 1;
$('#Panelgroup').find(".accordion-toggle").attr("href",  "#"+ (++hash));
$('#Panelgroup').find(".panel-collapse").attr("id",hash);
$('#Panelgroup').append(panel);
```

Comment: what are you going to do with those ids?

Comment: I want to distinguish each panel to be able to point on each panel and affect to it some actions.

Comment: the code you posted, where you call it? I mean you set `var hash = 1;` everytime, that you will get the same `id` for all your panel group right? @nermiiine

Comment: Yep I get the same id for all panel groups. I call it inside button click function

Comment: could you post that click function as well? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're resetting `hash` to 1 every time. You could make it into a global variable, and have a function that creates a new panel. Each time the function is called, you just increment the global variable by 1. This way `hash` won't be reset every time.

```
var hash = 1;

function createPanel() {
    // code to create panel

    hash++;
}
```

Comment: you are right, I didn't pay attention to this. Thank you. So I changed this line code to  that: `$("#OpenBtn").on("click",function()
{ panel += '<span class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#'+hash+'">' + $('#queuename').val(); hash++;
})`

Answer (score 1):

As I said in PO's comments, you are define your `var hash` every time the button clicked, in that case you will always get the same id.

there are more bugs in your code:

```
$('#Panelgroup').find(".accordion-toggle").attr("href",  "#"+ (++hash));
$('#Panelgroup').find(".panel-collapse").attr("id",hash);
```

this above two line of code will find `all` class with those name and update which is not what you want to do, you want to update the one you just created.

Also this line:

```
panel += '<div id="1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">';
```

you don't need to specific the `id` as it will be handled by something like this:

```
panel += '<div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="' + hash + '">';
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hash = 1;

  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
  console.log('hash-->'+hash);
    var panel = '<div class="panel panel-default">';
    panel += '<div class="panel-heading">';
    panel += '<h4 class="panel-title">';
    panel += '<span class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#' + hash + '">' + $('#queuename').val();
    panel += '</span>';
    panel += '</h4>';
    panel += '</div>';
    panel += '<div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="' + hash + '">';
    panel += '<div class="panel-body"></div>';
    panel += '</div>';
    panel += '</div>';
    panel += '</div>';
    $('#Panelgroup').append(panel);
    hash++;
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Panelgroup">yep</div>
<button id="btn">
  Create a panel
</button>
```

Comment: Exactly @Daniel H. Thank you